# RadNumeric TextBox is not accepting 9999999999999.999 value and convert it to 10000000000000

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one RadNumeric TextBox in c#. As I passed value 9999999999999.999 in that textbox and move ahead , it is converting that value automatically into 10000000000000. But I want to pass the value as it is. Can any one help ?

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="abcRadTextBox" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="3" 
    NumberFormat-NegativePattern="False" MaxLength="16" MinValue="0"
    MaxValue="9999999999999.999" Width="300px" Value="0.000" runat="server">
```

Comment: My code is:

 <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="abcRadTextBox" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="3" NumberFormat-NegativePattern="False" MaxLength="16" MinValue="0"                                              MaxValue="9999999999999.999" Width="300px"  Value="0.000" runat="server">

Comment: Please edit the code into the *text* of the question.

Comment: I suppose it's because of rounding. `Double` number format provides precision of about 14 decimal digits. You've run out of them here.
Try to test your case for lesser digits, say, 9999999.999.

Comment: Yes If I include 13 number of 9 with 2 precision, it is working. But with .999 it is not working specially with 13 number of 9.

Comment: @stop-cran: yeah you are right. I have exceed the limits

Comment: yes. Thanks. I exceed the limits